# Swift Button Background Image not appearing?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uibutton, uiimage

I have some very simple code to just programmatically set a button's background image to something but when the simulator runs it shows nothing. On the storyboard it shows that the image is present however, and again nothing shows.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var LetUsOutlet: UIButton!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 255, blue: 247, alpha: 1)
    self.view.backgroundColor = backgroundColor
    let backgroundButtonImage = UIImage(named: "round rectangle button.png") as UIImage?
    self.LetUsOutlet.setImage(backgroundButtonImage, for: .normal)
}

@IBAction func LetUsCreateMeal(_ sender: UIButton) {
}
@IBAction func CreateYourOwn(_ sender: UIButton) {
}
@IBAction func BrowseItems(_ sender: UIButton) {
}
@IBAction func ViewYourMeals(_ sender: UIButton) {
}

}
```

This is the simple code that I have so I am not sure why it isn't working properly. Below is my storyboard.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/EHlPH.jpg

The first button is where I try to programatically set the background, and the other 3 are when I just set the background image property within the storyboard.

This is what happens when it runs, showing that all background images are empty.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zD8mA.jpg

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: I seemed to have the image stored in the wrong place, I put it in a separate folder and not in the xassets folder.

Comment: can you share sample project?

Comment: Side comment - LetUsOutlet seems like a pretty poor name for that button, and also breaks the typical naming conventions. When I read `self.LetUsOutlet` I had no idea what I was looking at, and had to read the declaration to understand. If it was instead something like `createMealButton` with a lowercase first letter, that would follow typical naming convention and also be more clear wherever it's referenced. Variable and function names should start with lowercase letters.

Answer (score 1):

To change button background image you should use

```
LetUsOutlet.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named:"round rectangle button.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

Answer (score 0):

I mocked up an example - seemed to work okay for me. I suggest you check your button's constraints in IB

[image: Mock up]

Comment: Can you go into more detail with this? I constrained the button to the sides and the top of the view but it is still giving no image output.

Comment: I just did 4 constraints (top, bottom, left and right) - sounds like you'd be okay with yours. Check your image file name (I also have a pet hate for image names with spaces in) and ensure you have added it to the Assets.xcassets folder?

Answer (score 0):

change this line

```
let backgroundButtonImage = UIImage(named: "round rectangle button.png") as UIImage?
```

to this line

```
let backgroundButtonImage = UIImage(named: "round rectangle button")
```

and this line

```
self.LetUsOutlet.setImage(backgroundButtonImage, for: .normal)
```

to this

```
self.LetUsOutlet.setBackgroundImage(backgroundButtonImage, for: .normal)
```

Comment: hold on,  i will write some suggestions

Comment: 1- make sure that the image name is correct, case sensitive, also remove the extension from the code, 2-make sure that the outlet is correctly linked to it's IBOutlet var in you view controller (to do that, go to connections inspector when your button is selected in the storyboard, and make sure that button name is connected only once to your view controller under Referencing Outlets), tell me if you still have difficulty achieving this